# Android app works fine in emulator but crashes in real device

Tags: android, kotlin, crash

Here my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    myrv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)




    fetchJson()


}
fun fetchJson(){
    println("Attempting to fetch JSON")

    val url =BuildConfig.BASE_URL

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client= OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object:Callback{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed to execute request")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body,HomeFeed::class.java)


            runOnUiThread {
                myrv.adapter = MainAdapter(homeFeed)


            }
        }

    })

}
```

}

class HomeFeed(val content : List)

class Replik(val id: Int, val name: String, val imageUrl: String){

}

I'm feeling something is wrong in the runOnUiThread method. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: There may be a difference in the build API and your device API, post more details.

Comment: I added the error logcat

Comment: check out the permission

Comment: I gave this two permissions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Check your Firebase rules, it says paramter UID not found. Set Firebase rules in test mode and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"` in ImageView XML code.